# Android app is crashing due to V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: Signature not valid

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an android app in which I am using Google Maps API for Android v2. It was working fine in my phone until I upgraded my phone to Marshmallow. After updating my phone once I uninstalled it and again installed it using Android Studio it started having random crash. And every time the error was

> V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: Signature not valid. Found:
>   MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIEPmxzXDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA3MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UE
>   ChMHQW5kcm9pZDEWMBQGA1UEAxMNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzAeFw0xNTA5MjExMjE1MDNaFw00NTA5
>   MTMxMjE1MDNaMDcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQKEwdBbmRyb2lkMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BbmRy
>   b2lkIERlYnVnMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoTlzAY3DX0+vQmRo5stW
>   izwv76mghc1mbdxQnI16N6Ci/LFPOsiQLfYgt/qqitKCmo2kWWzfKNxN1Qyg5KaFdXRxpM8Ec7Xm
>   fkMX5cXzJOBDS62uWoDXpjiaXNOBeCvHDwC02EfOGfBd8csnO7sm3htHP8l2Jbn4uAY/zRQ+F4+C
>   Y477hSMxUvcDYoOoAcsye7pEu1bvPLSRxM44kjjhBFJlLYw6QtzE00khMrwdgBQwSdY0vtUPj9NM
>   hKGRuGoK/suIpd9e82EhqbUSlYsd62I/HV3390Eo/N2xXCsK7jrRdz6G9MjHfnUQLN80frZXGApl
>   LWiBti2soI9HhI++dQIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU3JFv8ivvt36O8WrsmkXRWYCDbEEwDQYJ
>   KoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAFLFGhfV6F4VOMCdKky6drHD10LzvR8/6QJzf/yp1QARzb3aR319g1my
>   f6Ffsaam9SKKj6OO92Jz7RTgUvZ6aD5sgRJXKcetmrGNWLGvsg0Rn+OxyEJ6dp4z49Oj5xyXjREp
>   6zv3QXxENib6EmPYKkFRS6cIe3QOMPsa6Q0KBKQFNnRAW+A+VBAVfEQYB1lgUMXUD+L9pc9EGNcN
>   zbatMn4FuWeyrhVaiSgMqyNHghUISgAZF76ImkQoPHVwgu7DzQQ44bXAwAbLFIwVhate/C0zN5ps
>   TjBZ4ojF0Z9mFM9tbLzBYCL2BpNCtYbp9uMpp4YtnX0+2sdxU6vi+ffSeAk=

Looks like updated Google Play services might be causing problem. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, my app is working without problems, but I see a lot of messages like this in logcat when I'm in debug mode, but not in all devices. The same app-debug.apk file shows this log in Android 4.4 (Huawei G6) and 5.1 (Moto G), but work without messages in 4.04 (Samsung Galaxy Tab) and 4.1.1 (Huawei G510).

Comment: I am still seeing the message in logcat but my app is working fine without any issues.

Comment: We are too dependent on google...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This logcat warning is caused by a bug introduced in Google Play Services 9.x. It can be safely ignored, I don't believe it causes a crash, so your crash may be caused by a different issue. The message should go away with a future update to play services.

This issue has been acknowledged by an engineer at Google in the [answer to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-not-using-the-google-maps-a)

Comment: yes you are right in my app crash issue was already fix only warning was coming and now it is also fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue recently. What caused it for me was when the phone auto updated Google Play Services to version 9.0.83.

The only solution I found was uninstalling the update and allowing Google Play services to re-update.

To remove the update:
Settings > Apps > Google Play services > Hit the three dots and uninstall updates. Then reinstall the updates through the play store.

Start the app and it should ask you to upgrade your Google Play services.

The version was originally 9.0.83 after doing these steps it downgraded to 8.7.03.

I don't feel like this is a solution since I have a few people testing my app and a few of them are having the same issue (the ones on version 9.0.83). I'm not too sure what changed with 9.0.83

Comment: It appears to be related to Google Play Services 9.0.83 indeed, problem is that on updating again it takes me back to 9.0.83. Adding a related Google+ thread in Android Development with a link to an issue that may be in the wrong project, but it appears there is no obvious place to report Google Play Services issues? well done, Google! https://plus.google.com/+ChristopheBeyls/posts/LC2XCSoaVBJ

Comment: No fixes for the errors being thrown. Though I did discover one of the libraries was causing my app to crash without throwing any errors after the update. Just needed to update to the latest version of the library and no more crashes.

Comment: I am unable to uninstall the updates. It is all greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same exception and I fixed it.

**Note: I am working on google analytics and was getting this exception. But my app was not crashing I was getting this in Logs. you can also try this solution.**

add this in project level gradle file.
  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'`

and this one for module level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

and move `below plugin at the end of file (at last line) of module level gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`

Comment: I did it and got error 
Error:org.gradle.api.GradleException: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

Comment: as I was working on google analytics, and it requires google-services.json file. but you dont need to add google services. you can just add google maps dependency.

Comment: @vishalgaurav you need to get/regenerate the config file from Google developer console ( link in comment below).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi you're right that entire play services dependency is not needed. but json config file is needed anyway.

Comment: yes agree @RuturajPatil I also needed google location services so I added this dependency. otherwise we should not add entire play services.

Comment: I just deleted the debug.keystore and its then rum the project it created new SHA1 then updated SHA1 in google console and my project stopped giving those messages. So basically I combined this suggestion and @prebilstatus suggestion and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same problem after changing the system and project config.

 Try these steps:

1. Check if you have enabled offline work for gradle: `Goto File > Settings > Gradle`. Deselect Offline Work if it's checked.
2. Then confirm if you have latest version of google services mentioned as dependencies in project level build.gradle:
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'.
   You can find latest version here: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
3. Clean and build the project after the gradle sync completes.

These steps solved the issue for me.
 In case you've changed the system used for building this app, make sure to update the SHA1 in your project on [Google Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and update the Maps API key in your android project.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue but your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: The build.gradle line should be 

 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

 and not
 
 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'

Comment: @The_Martian I want build tools as well as google services dependencies in my project classpath. here's my current project level build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/JcYV6sZZ . Hope this clears your incorrect understanding or confusion

Answer (score -1):

What fixed it for me was deleting the debug.keystore file found in the .android folder.

figured it out after reading that the debug.keystore file expires after a year and the system needs you to delete so it can create a new one.

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#expdebug

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue but your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: ``keytool -list -v -keystore "%HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android`` should tell you when it expires (``Valid from: ... until: ...``)

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue.I have tried your solution but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please do not do this. This caused authentication failed on the server. This is related to a recent updates in Android studio.

Comment: I am experimenting with firebase. This solution worked for me. I also had to update the server with SHA1 from the new debug keystore.

Comment: This is not a good answer. The deleting the keystore will not fix it