# Google maps in my app is not visible

Tags: android, android-keystore

When I launch my app I get the following error:

```
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): com.myapp.application signature not valid.  Found: 
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIEO0I8qTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA3MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UE
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): ChMHQW5kcm9pZDEWMBQGA1UEAxMNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzAeFw0xNTA0MjEyMDM4NDRaFw00NTA0
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): MTMyMDM4NDRaMDcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQKEwdBbmRyb2lkMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BbmRy
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): b2lkIERlYnVnMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn/4shkSGhYP1pwMY4bFc
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): dKuMg6JyTdUON6XF8VxifADMYd/WwgzsETT+AHZXlo6RwQFhtwbxrvmuhBOMip2ivhmRGT8JpBcI
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): FqjCOxLzw3B3psZhnioZwCBTKBrCau8/q0XW40lXa/OCy2wA4EZs2ThaqwqgdGwpKXN+qHNHAFAS
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): 0g/SdupsSID+WctlL2XdCo50Jq/bJJAWQBz1SL03xBWUikuiWKM6mz/6Up8oE4WtZhU7V83R7FYM
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): XmRU4CghlvczG+ujCrZwSsYttsZgz2nb4NY2w9fvevAXgSB/N6JfOatnccW5vmukkm6g12iysA9u
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): hS3EjVb01bKyMdoXhQIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUByeU0uE1tXyrL0UimKkJH2CbeXIwDQYJ
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): KoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBABPPel3zEbk6/ZzwfvIS0z8IqvYgzxzxSZFEAp+PrlEEyk+IVHQgQAVS
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): I6JM9rNkxR2hvQHP3V9pd2d5bYhsCBZFSn6drOmnBrnABXH8e4OdqN9fRcKn+acfbZ+yBvZoVbr/
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): IhRvRrpLDtDNnD4kUoLfTgw/Xygdiq5/aU5WSfXdrUx6Va0vg6uJZY6Yq4J4a/R+/T7lLwzQgerq
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): eNUvY9HbcmegJDKMGeyc4Po8akAt9gDRo4nswuP0Sve8oSMqBEfO8ItTsIPx3UVEXuYUeC8e8nwb
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(4962): fyhDXSFAo59Y1+NWcZNsGdum95YV8oZloF7+4fFqBwz7w0mb+M+JfY1sg7I=
```

I have read that debug.keystore default key has only 1 year validity, so one must delete it afterwards to let android studio generate a new one. Eventually I did it but the **error remains still.**

Google maps in my app is not visible anymore after this move...

Please help if you can.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208647/android-app-is-crashing-due-to-v-googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid

Comment: Is this happening on all android versions? On multiple devices?

Comment: Can we see the message above that one on your log file?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37281942/3457218

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This warning is caused by a bug introduced in Google Play Services 9.x. It can be safely ignored, it will not cause any issues with your app and should go away with a future update to play services.

This issue has been acknowledged by an engineer at Google in the [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-not-using-the-google-maps-a).

Comment: Thanks. I downgraded to ```compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.+' ``` and start working again.

Comment: @BrentM but due to that my map is not loading.Which is infecting our user base on production.

Comment: @adarsh From my experience this log message is not related to map loading failure. However it is impossible for me to comment on your situation. Check the SHA1 hashes listed in the developer API console as this is the most common cause of map loading failure.

Comment: strange but with the same SHA1 hash I am able to load map on other devices, and I am also getting same log as mentioned in this question. @BrentM

Answer (score 3):

When you delete debug.keystore then SHA1 fingerprint also changes. So you will need to get the latest SHA1 and then update it to the google map api developer console to get the Map.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution for me was to downgrade the Google Play Services to version 8.7.02 on my devices. I know it is not a long term solution but it works for my tests, and I hope I'll find a better solution in the future...