# Google maps api - Signature not valid

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app that uses Google Maps. But, when I am running the app I get the following warnign:

> V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid

I think it is related to the debug.keystore file, but I am not sure. Do you have any suggestions on how to give it a valid signature?

Comment: It seems an answer has been provided in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214165/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid).

Comment: @noogui I have already tried that without any luck. It still gives the error. Further more, the project is only 3 weeks old, so the key cannot have passed the one year limit of the debug-keystore. They also mentions the SHA1 fingerprint, but I havent added this to the Google maps key, so I don't think there is a problem either.

Comment: Oh so your debug-keystore exceeded the 1 year limit? Read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208647/android-app-is-crashing-due-to-v-googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid), one of the answers said to delete the debug.keystore file and replace it with a new one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-not-using-the-google-maps-a

Comment: I deleted the debug.keystore but the problem still remains. Do you have a solutions for the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Map Api v2 shows V/GoogleSignatureVerifier error message in log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281942/google-map-api-v2-shows-v-googlesignatureverifier-error-message-in-log)

Comment: This [question was answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37683914/3457218) and referred to a Google Developper knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

similar problems with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37401673/5327495) , someone has explained this why. Just trying to help