# Why do I get signature not valid onGoogle Maps Android API?

Tags: android, google-maps

My app was working fine with position updates on a device with 5.1.

Since then, I made two things:
Generating a signed apk.
Trying to deploy it to a 6.0 device.

I don't know what happened, but now google api's are not working even on my original device.

This is the part of the error log I think where problem is:

```
 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
 MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
 EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
 bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
 MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
 FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
 cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
 LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
 dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
 sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
 URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
 qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
 gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
 VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
 A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
 4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
 zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
 yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
 KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
 Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
 MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
05-18 11:44:43.691 2786-2865/born.speedsteer03 E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/born.speedsteer03-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-18 11:44:43.696 2786-2865/born.speedsteer03 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
```

Comment: how did you tested on device with 5.1 ? i means same signed apk

Comment: I was just cliking on the run button, with de debug keystore configured on project structure

Comment: I have the same problem... 8.4.0 and 9.0.0

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208647/android-app-is-crashing-due-to-v-googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid

Comment: I am also getting the same error but my app is working fine. Any solution for this?,  because I have tried all the solutions given below.

Answer (score 2):

Well if I'm not wrong you might have configured some hash key (Shah 1)at Google api console to use Google APIs.

Its working on your simulator or device through debug keystore(its a certificate) because you configured key is  debug keystore one.

Now you have generated signed apk and installed, you need add signed keystore Sha1 key to at Google api console.

Story is debug keystore sha1 you can use for development purpose. If generate singed apk file you need it's sha1 separately.

Comment: Now I have created a new keystore and added signed SHA1 key to google api console but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Sometimes it's getting location however, I don't know how if it keeps saying that signature is not valid

Comment: Wait for some time. It will take some time to get distributed too servers.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, thats a bug! It's just spurious logging though: Google Play services does some checking to see whether you are a Google app or a regular third party one.

As part of that, it calls the signature verifier and the logging ended up more verbose than intended - it will be fixed in a future version.This shouldn't affect the behavior of your app at all.

From Ian Barber Answer @ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0)

Comment: If you're copy-and-pasting this answer from [somewhere else](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37379789), you should also post a link to the source. Otherwise, it can be considered plagiarism. Thanks.

Comment: This could be the correct answer as everything is working fine.

Comment: You are right @Pang for correcting me. I got the answer from Ian Barber - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0

Hope this reference is helpful.