# GoogleSignatureVerifier signature not valid message (google play services 9.0.0)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have recently updated to the google play services library version 9.0.0, and I keep getting the following logcat message:

```
05-19 23:07:30.023 19237-19508/? V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: options.developer.com.developeroptions signature not valid.  Found:
```

While my app isn't using the google maps api but it is using the analytics, ads, and google plus apis.

The only mention in the documentation regarding the usage of the api key is when using google maps, or android places api.

I have also tried adding the 'com.google.android.geo.API_KEY' with a correct key but it didn't help.

here is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "options.developer.com.developeroptions"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1.06"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
}
```

Comment: the same with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'` and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'`

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @dit I haven't yet but I think it can related to the new firebase analytics, the app works fine also, there are no issues with any of the google apis just that message.

Comment: I am not using Firebase but I am getting this issue after recent Android studio updates. I guess it is a bug in Play-services.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrade google play service to 9.0.0. I use Google Map and GCM also. But application works fine

Comment: this google play service 9.0.0 issues

Comment: Duplicate of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281942/google-map-api-v2-doesnt-work-since-google-play-services-update-9-0-83

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Sorry, thats a bug! It's just spurious logging though: Google Play services does some checking to see whether you are a Google app or a regular third party one.

As part of that, it calls the signature verifier and the logging ended up more verbose than intended - it will be fixed in a future version.This shouldn't affect the behavior of your app at all.

Comment: So it doesn't do anything? We shouldn't worry?

Comment: Shouldn't worry.

Comment: Hi. Is there any link to the bug that we can check?

Comment: I downgraded to ```compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.+' ``` and start working again.

Comment: @ianbarber But this does affect the behavior of my app. It causes my app to go into ANR state. My log console outputs over 100 of this logs which lasts a while...then the anr trace file is written.

Comment: I deleted all the saved data from google play services on my phone and the logs aren't displaying anymore.

Comment: It does affect the behavior, when trying to launch an app with gms library included, the startup time is at least 5 seconds, and then that message is issued and then things are fine again. That's pretty close to ANR

Comment: down voted this answer though info is helpful! lol bug I would say

Comment: Sorry to contradict you @IanBarber but this does impact the app's behaviour the launch time is quite enormous as witnessed by Odaym. And also I see in the logs the presence of Firebase even I've never subscribed to it, that's quite intrusive.

Comment: I'm no longer getting this message after updating to the 9.2.0 library.

Comment: i have version 9.4.52 and i am getting this issue

Comment: still got this error in my logcat and map does't show what should i do??

Comment: Updgrade to the latest version (10.0.1 last time I looked), should go away.

Comment: I saw this error today and found maps to longer work in our app.  Can't tell whether there's a connection or not.  We're using maps v2.

Comment: 6 months later, it is still there... Having the latest GooglePlayServices (10.2.98) so not sure what you meant by "it will be solved in next version". Just a friendly reminder @IanBarber

Comment: @Ewoks are you seeing it at high volumes? If so, could you link log output and note your client and APK versions? Its still harmless, but it would be interesting to see what you're seeing.

Comment: @IanBarber I am trying to use the latest downloader library and licensing library and found a bug when doing so. Could you please review if my fix is valid? https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion/pull/1

Comment: these logs are correct, I am facing this issue in android 9 and below. The map is previewing successfully but google map object is not initialized. GetMapAsync never called. Tried every solution. And Map is working fine on Android 10 and above

Answer (score 2):

You will find a lot of solutions on the net, but the only one who works for me was to downgrade the Google Play Services to 8.7.02 version on my devices. I hope Google will fix this error rapidly :')

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, its the Google Play Services 9 update to the device.  You can have these options until google fix the bug:

- Safely ignore it
- Downgrade your phone/device using Settings->Apps->Google play services->(three dots on top right menu)->Uninstall

  If the Disable/Force Stop buttons are greyed out you may need to remove the app from being a 'device administrator' before uninstalling it.

Google plus blog relating to the bug: https://plus.google.com/+ChristopheBeyls/posts/LC2XCSoaVBJ

Removing/Recreating the keystore.debug file is unlikely to help.  If you've done this already then you'll need to create a new one using the 'map api developer console'

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you entered your SHA sinature and package name correctly.
2. make sure you have enabled your GoogleMaps Api in your ApiManager>Overview after creating your project in api console(search it in google)
3. make sure you have allowed internet permissions in your manifest file
4. in your build file use compile 
   'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1' (works for me)

In my case i missed out step 3 .

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the gms library to 9.0.1 and delete all the saved data from google play services on my phone and the logs weren't displaying anymore. They were causing me AND state in my app before, which was giving me major headaches why this was happening.