# Firebase Error What Happened Here

Tags: android, firebase

When i send a notification from firebase just show notification title. it was working but now it does not work.

```
  private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentTitle("Bildirim");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setTicker("selam dost.mesaj geldi");
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

And i am taking message like this now : "V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found" What happened to this ?

Comment: The error message is not the cause of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37379789/4815718

Comment: what did you change before the code does not work? try to put a log or breakpoint in that method to see if that method is called

Comment: The `showNotification` method looks normal. I think what happened is the method was not called that time. So try to check the `onMessageReceived` method.