# Google map fragment crashing

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am using fragment in my xml to show the google map.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googleMapContainer"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

It loads in some phones but in phones like Xiomi Redmi Note 3 it fails to open the class and crashes.
In the activity i declare it like this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMapContainer);
googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
```

Logcat

```
09-01 11:58:45.557 22585-22585/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-01 11:58:45.577 22585-22585/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
09-01 11:58:45.627 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
09-01 11:58:45.627 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: install
09-01 11:58:45.627 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
09-01 11:58:45.677 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.
09-01 11:58:45.677 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bison.d2d1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
09-01 11:58:45.677 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: 4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: 4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bison.d2d1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
09-01 11:58:45.687 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
09-01 11:58:45.707 22585-22613/com.bison.d2d1 D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
09-01 11:58:45.717 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:1
09-01 11:58:45.717 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.flags, version >= 1
09-01 11:58:45.737 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bison.d2d1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
09-01 11:58:45.737 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:3
09-01 11:58:45.737 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 3
09-01 11:58:45.737 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
09-01 11:58:45.737 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
09-01 11:58:45.747 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.DelegateLastPathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodlmp_xxhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]]
09-01 11:58:45.747 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:1
09-01 11:58:45.747 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.flags, version >= 1
09-01 11:58:45.777 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrash reporting API initialized
09-01 11:58:45.777 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg@31928a69
09-01 11:58:45.777 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.
09-01 11:58:45.787 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
09-01 11:58:45.787 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-01 11:58:45.817 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
09-01 11:58:45.817 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-01 11:58:45.817 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: install
09-01 11:58:45.817 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta: Failed to find this app in the PackageManager
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: io.crash.air
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:281)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.beta.DeviceTokenLoader.getZipInputStreamOfApkFrom(DeviceTokenLoader.java:63)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.beta.DeviceTokenLoader.load(DeviceTokenLoader.java:35)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.beta.DeviceTokenLoader.load(DeviceTokenLoader.java:21)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.cache.AbstractValueCache.get(AbstractValueCache.java:39)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta.getBetaDeviceToken(Beta.java:146)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta.getDeviceIdentifiers(Beta.java:114)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager.getDeviceIdentifiers(IdManager.java:281)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.answers.SessionMetadataCollector.getMetadata(SessionMetadataCollector.java:34)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler$4.run(AnswersEventsHandler.java:119)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22631/com.bison.d2d1 E/Beta:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-01 11:58:45.867 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.10.127
09-01 11:58:45.897 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: install
09-01 11:58:45.897 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
09-01 11:58:46.087 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
09-01 11:58:46.117 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
09-01 11:58:46.137 22585-22585/com.bison.d2d1 E/token: eNssyTSITtY:APA91bHawo1yC85f2xneitCONp8f57oPrFjkwHLn9PIyb_0ZFfAQmZNRqUwPjiDKi7Bp3O68kA2cGZlj61zSexZBp3GfFAAwC4437L6RG-K5zMgbXcW3t2lSuFZhSdPIzrvugbRJyUlp
09-01 11:58:46.647 22585-22602/com.bison.d2d1 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 76(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 66MB/82MB, paused 5.533ms total 21.969ms
```

Comment: Post logcat error.

Comment: it simply comes back to the previous activity.

Comment: You've said app crashes. Now you are saying "comes back to previous activity". Where is a truth? Logcat seems fine to me. I bet the problem is related to `getMap()` method. It is now deprecated. Try to use `getMapAsync()`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the phone model you provided, but if you're using google play services for maps, is there a chance that google play services is not installed on that phone?

Comment: @Iman they are installed

Comment: @ArpanSharma Try changing  "getChildFragmentManager()"  to  "getSupportFragmentManager()" I have no idea why you are using childFragmentManager.

Comment: first i used it in an activity using getSupportFragmentManager() then it showed this error.So i tried adding it with a viewpager fragement using getChildFragmentManager(). But the result is same

Comment: @skywall its not exactly a crash as you have seen the logcat.It just doesnt load and then comes to the home page

Comment: What about memory in the phones which is crashing.If it is low there is a known issue .

Comment: 3gb avilable.It doesnot have a external card

Comment: Its a fragment issue.If i remove the fragment the problem is gone.But if i add even a map view it crashes on xiomi redme note 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related with hardware acceleration .I had to assign true value to it for the specific activity scope , in the manifest, where the google map was being displayed.

```
<activity android:name="com.bison.activities.MyActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        </activity>
```

This issue is generated because in some phones the available ram is unable to draw complex view like map and hence the application crashes. So hardware acceleration ensures the use of more physical resources like ram etc and hence avoiding the crash.
Also, it can be enabled on Application level or to a specific activity or to a view only.

For detailed info on the issue [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) is the google developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error on not enabling multi dex (android allows only 64K methods on a dex). look into the link below to enable multi dex.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in library.Try using a lower version on googlePlayServices.Refer to the following thread: [Bug in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0)

Comment: I read somewhere that it is a bug in library. Try using another version of GooglePlayServices.

Comment: can you specify a version?

Comment: Well, what I am using is ''com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' and it is working fine.

Comment: But even if i is  a play services error.SHouldn't it effect all the phones.