# Android MapView no longer working, even after using updated google tutorial

Tags: android, android-mapview, gmsmapview

I followed the tutorial step by step to setup google maps on my android app, but I keep receiving this error:

````
```W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6```
````

I've tried both in different emulators and physical devices, but nothing works.
The same apk I compiled a few weeks ago also stopped working.

Comment: Please check google api key is present in project and google developer console.

Comment: @AndroidGeek that's the first thing I've done. It's not working

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0

Comment: @AndroidGeek I read that before posting. It doesn't help

Comment: Have the same issue if I use com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment works perfectly but if I use com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView I got this error:

    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.components.maps.sample, sha256=[5fc076bde26eb5d0d4519d6a593aa1d2c8a461f1bfeba21e3a91e94b7decXXXX], atk=false, ver=220615044.true (go/gsrlt)
//
With the same key and using com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment works perfectly, not sure what's happening.

Comment: @EmanuelAmiguinho have you had any success fixing this? I'm facing a similar issue and can't seem to find a resolution

Comment: Hi @kimyas78 not yet, I ended up using the SupportMapFragment which this error still happens on the logs but the map renders properly, I will have to find a solution for the View soon too to be honest, but not there yet, will update it here accordingly.